# SQL query for combining data in same column of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (tblCity) with State name and city name as columns.

I have a requirement to show on screen State name and city names (all cities of a state as csv).

I created a table variable, iterated through my tblCity table for every state and accomplished this.

However I would like to know if there is any easy way around.

Comment: Please post some sample data and the query you've tried so far.

Comment: Show some code what you have done? So that other would provide some better solution if any.

Answer (score 0):

you can use coalesce to do that.

```
Declare @city varchar(Max)
Set @city=''
Select @city=@city + Coalesce([City]+ ', ','') from tblCity
Select Left(@city,LEN(@city)-1) as [City]
GO
```